# Webpack + Sequelize: Import model definitions from files

Tags: node.js, webpack, sequelize.js, serverless-framework

I'm using Sequelize in a Serverless project, which uses Webpack to bundle the function files into a single script.

I have a `models` folder, which contains the model definitions:

`models/ExampleModel.js`

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';

module.exports = sequelize => {
  class ExampleModel extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // handle associations
    }
  }

  ExampleModel.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    ...
  }, {
    sequelize,
  });

  return ExampleModel;
}
```

I then have an `models/index.js` file, which contains a loader to import these files and call the `associate` function to set up associations:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_URL);
const base = path.resolve('src/models')
const db = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(base)
  .filter((file) => {
    console.log(file)
    const returnFile = (file.indexOf('.') !== 0)
      && (file !== 'index.js')
      && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
    return returnFile;
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    const filepath = path.join(base, file);
    const model = require(filepath)(sequelize)
    db[model.name] = model;
  });


Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

export default db;
```

The problem is that this function is obviously executed at runtime (when you try to import a model), so Webpack doesn't recognize that the model files are required and hasn't included them in the build.

To get around this, I tried adding the below to my Webpack config:

```
plugins: [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin({
    patterns: [
      { from: 'src/shared/v3/models', to: 'src/models' },
    ]
  }),
  ...
]
```

When I look at the output from Webpack, it has successfully copied the models directory to `src/models`:

```
.webpack/test-models
└── src
    ├── models
    │   ├── ExampleModel.js
    │   └── index.js
    └── scripts
        ├── test-models.js
        └── test-models.js.map
```

However when `test-models.js` is run, it fails with the error:

> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/redacted/.webpack/test-models/src/models/ExampleModel.js

The `console.log` in the filter function of `index.js` successfully logs all the model file names, and the files exist, so I can't work out why the `require` call can't find the file.

Running the below successfully lists the content of the file in the error message:

```
$ cat /Users/redacted/.webpack/test-models/src/models/ExampleModel.js
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';

module.exports = sequelize => {
  class ExampleModel extends Model {
  ...
```

I've checked the permissions of the copied files, and they're all `-rw-r--r--` so should be readable by the script.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet? I'm with the same problem.

Comment: I ended up just writing a quick standalone script to get the directory listing, build an `index.js` which imports each file individually (hardcoded) then exports, and added this to the build pipeline

Answer (score -2):

```
Require function not support so use directly import it

import workqueue from "./php_dev/models/workqueue";
import workqueuetype from "./php_dev/models/workqueuetype";
import WqTypeItemAssc from "./php_dev/models/wqtypeitemassc";
import WorkItemList from "./php_dev/models/workitemlist"; 

db.Database_name= {
    WorkQueue : workqueue(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes),
    WorkQueueType : workqueuetype(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes),
    WqTypeItemAssc : WqTypeItemAssc(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes),
    WorkItemList : WorkItemList(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).